# Metro App ListView Binding Item Issue

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5, observablecollection

I am experiencing a unique problem with my **Metro App**. The problem is as follows:

I have a `Custom Serializable ObservableCollection` which is capable of `Sorting` and `Filtering`. This object is then bound to a `ListView`. Everything works great until I `Navigate` away from my `MainPage` to a `SecondPage`.

On the `SecondPage` work in the `MainPage` continues and the `Custom Serializable ObservableCollection` continues to `Fill` up with data. When I `Navigate` away from the `SecondPage` back to the `MainPage`, there's a noticeable problem, i.e:

Any items added to `Custom Serializable ObservableCollection` while on the `SecondPage` appear as **Blank** `ListViewItems`. I've been struggling to figure out what's going on here for days. I'm extremely desperate for a solution, so any help would be much appreciated.

I've created a `Mock` application to demonstrate the issue, which can be found here:
[Mock Project](https://bqqq0g.bn1.livefilestore.com/y2p8bRMktx6uPOTBERAEh6miarpNHJdqujx1Dva5zuWg1_QoDKfBlpOkRnAALGoQxjpdejdbJ_HsZ1pjlQCuPaCdGnV45huZDfBhAO81NCDrHk/MetroAppCustomCollectionNavigationTest.zip?download&psid=1)

**To see the problem in action:**

1. Select a Category.
2. Select a Product.
3. Wait for a few **Product Variants** to appear.
4. Click on `SecondPage` button.
5. Wait for a minute or so on the `SecondPage`.
6. Click Back button on `SecondPage`.
7. Now you should see some **Blank** `ListViewItems`

The **Blank** `ListViewItems` are the ones that were added when on the `SecondPage`. You will also notice that any new items added NOW while the `MainPage` is back in focus, appear fine.

**I AM WILLING TO OFFER A BOUNTY BUT CAN'T AFFORD TO WAIT 2 DAYS, NEED AN ANSWER A.S.A.P. FIRST CORRECT SOLUTION WILL RECEIVE 50 POINTS!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED thanks to Microsoft:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/83c2534e-82df-4707-8ecb-f093e7f58e33

```
public MainPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();

     NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
     this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     lvProductVariants.ItemsSource = null; // Reset 
      Bind();
}
```